# LINQ to create list of strings from indexes stored in int[]

Tags: c#, linq

This is what I have:

```
int[] indexes; // it contains indexes that are "good"
string[] words; // many words
List<string> result;
```

And I would like to do this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.Count(); ++i)
    if (indexes.Contains(i))
        result.Add(words[i]);
```

In only one line, by LINQ I guess :) How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming a distinct set of indexes. We can just grab each word rather than starting from the words and finding matching indexes.

```
List<string> result = indexes.Select(i => words[i]).ToList();
```

Note that this version is much faster assuming indexes is smaller than words. (100 indexes and 20,000 words would be 20 million operations in yours and 100 in mine).

Comment: Doesn't that leave you with an `IEnumerable<int>`?  Still need .ToList()?

Comment: @EricJ.: Question asked for a List, but I have found that people tend to ask for whatever their algorithm functions with, not what they actually need. Fixed to match the question.

Comment: Agreed, it's often true that people use concrete classes rather than interfaces, when interfaces provide for better code reuse.

Comment: @EricJ.: Actually `IList` is the interface that matches. In this case it is the difference between "I need an ordered enumerable" vs "I need a list of items". The latter is more general so if appropriate it is more flexible.

Comment: Yes, `IList<int>` would be the appropriate interface.  However, I agree that it's not clear whether he needs the additional contract elements vs. `IEnumerable<int>`.  It would be inefficient to instantiate a `List<int>` just to return an `IList<int>` interface, if he does not need the ability to index elements.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not one liner but:

```
result = Enumerable.Range(0, words.Count())
      .Where(indexes.Contains)
      .Select(idx => words[idx])
      .ToList();
```

Comment: You can totally write that in one line :-)

Comment: What's the deal with `Where(indexes.Contains)`?  Thought you had to write `Where(w => indexes.Contains(w))`.

Comment: @EricJ.: As long as the function type matches that is valid. In this case they are both `Func<string, bool>`.

Comment: it's method group, it's equal to `Where(w => indexes.Contains(w)` . but actually I don't know why I  couldn't think indexes.Select :)